# javax @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW) with condition?

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, ejb, required

I wondered if it was possible to put a condition in transaction management , like having a service(class or method) with TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED and if this service is called by a defined service/method , we make a new transaction.

A kind of condition according to the method/class call ?

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot using `@Transaction` with EJB3.x. Either your container manages your EJB transaction or you can, by injecting `UserTransaction` (when `TransactionManagement` is set to `TransactionManagementType.BEAN`). That annotation is to be used with CDI managed beans.

Comment: i've edited the question, i was talking aboutt transactionAttribute.

Comment: Not in any standard way. Which means you're probably trying to do something weird.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible. What you can do is leave your main service as `REQUIRED`, and create a new Wrapper/Facade Service for your special case which has `REQUIRES_NEW`. Then any services that must have a new transaction calls this new wrapper service.